# Testing AdBannerView with Real Ads from iAd Network

Tags: ios, iad

Is there a way to test iOS app with AdBannerView on the simulator or a developers device with real ads instead of test advertisement?

I haven't submitted the App yet and I was wondering if the above is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sometimes seen real adverts just start working even though test adverts should be displayed, but I don't think there's a way to actually force this to happen. Apple are not going to give you a method for this since they don't want you tapping on adverts whilst you're testing the app. Also, you shouldn't need to test live ads anyway. If all is working with test ads, then everything will work fine with live ads.

Comment: well the reason I am concerned about this is because of this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755601/adbannerview-warning-message

Comment: That you should not be worried about. And how is testing live ads going to help with that anyway? The warning is that the ad is partially or fully obscured. As long as you're not loading an ad and deliberately putting it behind another view so it can't be seen, you're OK.