# ADBannerView Warning Message

Tags: ios, iad, adbannerview

I am using AdBannerView and I see the following message in the Application Output window while debugging my app.

> ADBannerView: WARNING A banner view (0x98c0c40) has an ad but may be
>   obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view.

I wonder why is it throwing this message, as the test Ad seems to be working fine. Do i need to be concerned about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely do not need to be worried about this message.  It's printed in some of the weirdest circumstances for everyone (I've had banners that we're perfectly visible, or in the process of animation that print that message).  One can see the value of this message in very specific circumstances, but obviously it's a little annoying at times.

Comment: I have noticed that it actually happens when i navigate from the banner screen to the next one and probably because the transition animation is causing the banner while in the middle of animation to behave as if its been obscure. If i hide the banner in ViewWillDisappear event, then i don't see this message anymore. I wonder if its the correct solution?

Comment: There's no specific way to get rid of the warning, which is good because it's a benign issue.

Comment: If you can see the banner, then why should you care?

Comment: It is also my experience that these warnings can be spurious and not an actual problem. You'll need to determine for yourself if it is actually being obscured.